# avoid fragment pop back stack until fragment transaction finished

Tags: android, fragment

Imaging that i have 3 fragment :  A , B , C
my fragments will replace in a FrameLayout in my activity.
each transactions of each fragment have custom animations for input and output (slide in and slide out), my fragments will push to back stack.
in onBackPress method of my activity i pop fragments if are available.
and my problem: if i go from fragment A to B and this animation begin started and i immediately press back button my app crashed with this exception:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                   Process: 
>                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4405)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4246)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4186)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4159)
>                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1001)
>                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1165)
>                                                                       at android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:1747)
>                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1631)
>                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManager.java:570)
>                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
>                                                                       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5969)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:801)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)

my fragment class code is:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);
        initViews(view);
    }

    return view;
}
```

is possible to avoid popBackStack until transaction is running? or better solution?